# How to implement a WPF circular progress bar with a linear gradient brush

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, lineargradientbrush

How do I implement a WPF circular progress bar with the following linear gradient brush:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="LinearGradientProgressBrush">
    <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.25"/>
    <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.50"/>
    <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.75"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

As the circular progress bar advances, the color needs to change at the end point of the arc, with previous arc colors staying the same. In other words, the Blue color wont start being painted until the circular progress bar gets to 75%.

Comment: [This](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2009/02/Graphical-Paths-with-Gradient-Colors.html) should get you on the right track

Comment: I would use an image brush rather than a lineargradientbrush. Rotate the image and use it as a fill.